# iPhone: How to play sound that ignores volume and ringer switch settings?

Tags: iphone, audio

The app FoneHome is able to do both:

- ignore the ringer switch when it's set to silence
- play at a high volume regardless of system volume setting

I see documentation about the playback Audio Session category not respecting the ringer switch but not the volume. Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1):

It is technically possible to change the system volume through the private AVSystemController class in Celestial.framework, but causes problems with Apple's approval process. FoneHome recently was taken down - its possible that the back and forth between them and Apple was because of this reason.